# Selecting and deleting takes more time in oracle stored procedure - Perfornamce tuning

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, database-performance

We are having a 20 million set of records in oracle table. We are trying to transfer 14 million of records to another table on another schema.

Example: **Table1** is with 20 million records on **schema1** and 14 million records should get transferred to **Table2** on **schema2**.

We are selecting, inserting and deleting the records using cursor. After the records are inserted into **table2** we are deleting the same set of records in **table1**.

We are using the below stored procedure to implement that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA1"."ARCHIVE"(FROM_ARCHIVE timestamp, TO_ARCHIVE timestamp,PROCESS_DATE_ARCHIVE timestamp)
AS
    CURSOR C_EXTRACT IS
        SELECT
            COL1,
            COL2,
            COL3,
            .
            .
            .
            .
            COL65
        FROM
            TABLE1
        WHERE 
            UPPER(COL5) ='XXX' AND COL8 >= FROM_ARCHIVE AND COL8 <= TO_ARCHIVE AND UPPER(COL24) NOT IN ('YYY','ZZZ'); 

    FOR C_EXTRACT_REC IN C_EXTRACT
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            INSERT
            INTO
                SCHEMA2.TABLE2
                (
                    COL1,
                    COL2,
                    COL3,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    COL65
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    C_EXTRACT_REC.COL1,
                    C_EXTRACT_REC.COL2,
                    C_EXTRACT_REC.COL3,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .                   
                    C_EXTRACT_REC.COL65
                );
        END;
    END LOOP;


    FOR C_EXTRACT_REC_DEL IN C_EXTRACT
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            DELETE
            FROM
                TABLE1
            WHERE
                COL1 =C_EXTRACT_REC_DEL.COL1;
        END;
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Selecting and deleting takes more time to execute it. Is there any way to tune up the performance so that select and delete query executes with less time.

Using this stored procedure, for selecting, inserting and deleting 12 records it takes 12 minutes and for selecting, inserting and deleting 1 lac records it takes 30 mins.

**Note**: We are using **partitioning** a column and **sub-partitioning** a column using list in **TABLE1**.

Please help us.

Comment: I see that you've used EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS to hide any errors, so that if one occurs you will not know what it was. This seems to be to be unhelpful.

Comment: Also, what columns are you partitioning on? Is this a frequent operation, because partitioning could make it much more efficient.

Comment: @DavidAldridge We are partitioning COL22 and Sub-partitioning COL24 using list in TABLE1. We are partitioning for every month i.e. JAN2011, FEB2011,.......,DEC2013. Is it possible to DROP the partition for JAN2011 and after executing the stored procedure for deleting the data for a week in JAN2011 and also is it possible to recreate the partition for JAN2011.

Comment: Are you familiar with partition exchange? Have a look to see if you can use that.

Comment: No I am not familiar with partition exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You are hammering your database with 28M individual statements. SQL is a set processing language. It's better to use 2 statements inside your procedure, like this: [untested]

```
create or replace procedure schema1.archive
( from_archive timestamp
, to_archive timestamp
, process_date_archive timestamp
)
as
begin
  insert into schema2.table2
  ( col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    .
    .
    .
    .
    col65
  )
  select col1
  ,      col2
  ,      col3
  ,      .
         .
         .
         .
         col65
  from   table1
  where  upper(col5) ='XXX'
  and    col8 >= from_archive
  and    col8 <= to_archive
  and    upper(col24) not in ('YYY','ZZZ')
  ; 
  delete table1
  where  upper(col5) ='XXX'
  and    col8 >= from_archive
  and    col8 <= to_archive
  and    upper(col24) not in ('YYY','ZZZ')
  ;
end;
```

This procedure achieves the same, but much faster.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: We have tried this but it is taking more time to execute the delete query.

Comment: Impossible. One delete statement using a full table scan will always beat 14M single row delete statements. Are there database triggers on the table?

Comment: We are having many indexes, foreign key constraints and partitions and sub-partitions in table1. For deleting zero record its execution time is 24mins.

Comment: If possible in your situation, you can drop the indexes prior to the execution of this procedure, and recreate them afterwards.

Comment: we are in awkward situation. There are totally 21 indexes and we made the index unusable and we executed the delete statement and after that we have rebuild it. For rebuilding all 21 indexes it is taking 84 mins. Each index is taking 4 mins. So if we are running the stored procedure for a day then it is more time consuming one.

Comment: Perhaps this is all useful information that should be in the question, including the partitioning specification.

Comment: Why not rebuild multiple indexes at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are transfering most of the data. If so, instead of delete, do the following:

```
create table3 as
  select * from table1
  where  not (upper(col5) ='XXX'
  and         col8 >= from_archive
  and         col8 <= to_archive
  and         upper(col24) not in ('YYY','ZZZ'));

drop table1;
alter table3 rename to table1;
-- Recreate indexes, foreign keys, etc.
```

Also take advice from another answer and make insert into table2 also bulk.